# "Could not happen" vs. "could have not happened"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which one is correct?

> These changes **could have not happened** without outstanding help
>   kindly provided by the queen.
>
> These changes **could not happen** without outstanding help kindly
>   provided by the queen.

The changes happened last year and thus the process of changing is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*These changes could not have happened . . .* describes changes that have already been made. *These changes could not happen . . .* describes changes which are currently being made.

Answer (score 2):

I would use neither but write

> These changes could not have happened without outstanding help kindly
>   provided by the queen.

Comment: Thank you. Also, when would we use the second case - _could not happen_. Is is grammatically correct to use such a format in past-tense sentences?